Need to update the jar file without modifying other contents
Need to update the JAR with an file, but when trying to update all other contents are getting deleted.
Jar File size:
 du -sh test-SNAPSHOT.jar
 66M    test-SNAPSHOT.jar

jar -uf test-SNAPSHOT.jar test-INF/classes/cert
du -sh test-SNAPSHOT.jar
4.0K    test-SNAPSHOT.jar

Need to update the JAR with an file, but when trying to update all other contents are getting deleted.

A JAR file is just a ZIP file without a different name. So what stops you from using a program for editing zip files?

When i try to update the jar file using this command "jar -uf test-SNAPSHOT.jar test-INF/classes/cert" All other contents inside the jar file is getting deleted.

Not sure it's due to mac

Just rename it that the file extension is .zip, make your changes there (you don't need the jar command) and then rename it back

List before and after: jar tf test-SNAPSHOT.jar | sort What's the diff?

Try with jar uf test-SNAPSHOT.jar test-INF/classes/cert (so uf instead of -uf). Maybe you're using a jar from Java 8 or older.

You can try using software like 7zip. Open the jar with 7 zip and drag and drop the new classes into it to copy the old classes.
